# How to fix ' ValidationError: users validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Receiving an error while sending post request in postman

I'm creating a new pin for a mapping app. This is my schema for the pin. I am requring a username title and description as a string. I am then requiring rating longitute and latitude as a number. once entered and sent, i recieve an validation error.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PinSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 60,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
    },
    long: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    lat: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Pin", PinSchema);
```

This is the route for the pin.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Pin = require("../models/Pin");


//create a pin
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const newPin = new Pin(req.body);
  try {
    const savedPin = await newPin.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedPin);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//get all pins
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pins = await Pin.find();
    res.status(200).json(pins);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the error that im getting

```
"_message": "Pin validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Pin validation failed: lat: Path `lat` is required., long: Path `long` is required., rating: Path `rating` is required., desc: Path `desc` is required., title: Path `title` is required., username: Path `username` is required."
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this error is invalid type to store in db. Like rating is number type but if you are passing a value which can not be convert to number then it will give the same error.

In this case you declared this 'lat' with 'required: true' and it seems you didn't add this value on your POST body. If you want to declare it later you should delete 'required: true'